# Auto complete textbox in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose in my grid contains, the columns named Item Code, Item Name, Quantity, Price etc.. then all columns should be editable and at the same time existing data items should be listed as auto complete.

Comment: by autocomplete you mean extract current saved value or like google type auto suggest text box ?

Comment: If you want something like the google search textbox, then try Telerik's RadComobox. Further explanation here http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radcombobox-features-autocomplete.html

Comment: I mean current saved value.